# IE add-on/toolbar in c#

Tags: internet-explorer, toolbar

I wish to develop a toolbar for IE using c# and visual studio 2010. I need some useful links related to this topic. Please provide me some useful links.

Comment: @scunliffe: Flagged for the LMGTFY link, *and* for subverting the system using bit.ly. http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/15650/ban-lmgtfy-let-me-google-that-for-you-links

Comment: @Robert - ah yes, caught.  I think Jeff-n-Joel have often indicated that this type of question: "I'm too lazy to Google it" isn't the type of "good" question that helps the community.  If the community does feel that this is a good question then I guess it will collect answers and remain rather than be flagged and closed.

Answer (score 1):

http://www.codeproject.com/KB/dotnet/IE_toolbar.aspx

Answer (score 1):

I have an answer here in SO about IE extensions using C# take a look... it might be helpful.

[How to get started with developing Internet Explorer extensions?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5643819/developing-internet-explorer-extensions/5740004#5740004)

Answer (score 0):

Check:

- [Add-in Express and Internet Explorer](http://www.add-in-express.com/programming-internet-explorer/developing-addons.php)
- [Video: Developing Internet Explorer extensions, end-to-end demo](http://www.add-in-express.com/creating-addins-blog/2011/06/13/internet-explorer-extensions-development-video/)