# IE addon in C# able to communicate with mysql

Tags: c#, .net, mysql, internet-explorer, add-on

I have a simple question. Is there a possibility to make an add-on for IE, in C# that can connect to a MySQL database? Basically what I need is to gather some text from a page and insert it into a database via a context menu command.

I just need to know if this is possible, and maybe if you can point me some libraries or frameworks that will help me.

Thank you very much!

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2754226/ie-add-on-toolbar-in-c-sharp

Comment: What makes you think this is not possible?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you want to build an IE addon I recommend you to take a look at: http://www.add-in-express.com/programming-internet-explorer/index.php. 
You can connect to the mysql db like you would from any .NET application.